# liblzf compress error Undefined symbols lzf_compress C++

Tags: c++, compression, lzf

I am trying to use LZF C++. However, when I compile it, it give me this error:

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cppapplication_2 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/lzf_c.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/lzf_d.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "lzf_compress(void const*, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I already included lzf.h.

Comment: try to compile with  **-framework CoreFoundation**  flag

Comment: I try that, but it still give me same error.

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at [lzf.h](http://cvs.schmorp.de/liblzf/lzf.h?revision=1.18&view=markup) shows that it doesn't account for C++.  Normally you would see something like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Function declarations go here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

So that the C++ compiler knows to look for C symbols.  I'm guessing what is happening with your code is that the C++ compiler is requesting whatever it mangles the C++ symbol `lzf_compress` to instead of just the C symbol `lzf_compress`.  However, since the actual code is in a C file your build system probably uses the C compiler (not the C++ compiler) to compile it.

If I were you I would fix the header, and file a bug (with a patch) to get the fix upstream.

If you don't want to fix `lzf.h` I *think* you could just do something like

```
extern "C" {
#include "lzf.h"
}
```

The other "solution" would be to just compile everything with the C++ compiler.  I'm not certain liblzf is valid C++, though, so that may or may not work.

Comment: Debian already do that liblzf-3.6/debian/patches/0001-Make-sure-that-the-library-is-linked-with-C-symbols.patch

Comment: That's good, but it's probably not a good idea to rely on that unless you *know* your code will never be used anywhere other than a Debian derivative.  Basically, unless it's throw-away code you should protect against the `extern "C"` being omitted.  That said, you probably shouldn't use LZF for anything unless you have a very good reason; AFAICT it's unmaintained, and there are much better options these days.